# How to get values of nested object by a single string key in javascript?

Tags: javascript

There is an object `info` which describes as below:-

```
    let info = {
        "person" : {
            "name" : "Something",
            "age" : 1
        }
    }
```

I want to access the property `name` and I want to access it like `info["person.name"]`, how it can be done?

Comment: You can't, you can use a method (custom one or from a library) and then traverse the object properties.

Comment: `Info['person']['name']`? Or `info.person.name`?

Comment: @0xc14m1z can't i do it with some function overloading or something?

Comment: I don't think so... maybe with a Proxy applied, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: @wentjun i know those thing but i want to access the object as mentioned above

Comment: @0xc14m1z yeah i tried proxy and it works but in react js proxy does not update after using ```setState```

Comment: Why you need to access a property by a string in Formik? Maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: formik does it and i want to know how that works?

Comment: Ahh got it. Well they probably have a method that traverse the object :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190961/discussion-between-user8751232-and-0xc14m1z).

Comment: I looked at their code out of curiosity: here is the method to deeply get a value: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/src/utils.ts#L8

Answer (score 1):

You could use a proxy like this:

```js
const customAccessor = obj => new Proxy(obj, {
  set(_, keys, value) {
    const recSet = (object, [key, ...remaining], value) => {
      if (remaining.length === 0) {
        object[key] = value;
      } else {
        recSet(object[key], remaining, value);
      }
    }
    recSet(_, keys.split('.'), value);
  },
  get(_, keys) {
    const recGet = (object, [key, ...remaining]) => {
      if (remaining.length === 0) {
        return object[key];
      } else {
        return recGet(object[key], remaining);
      }
    }
    return recGet(_, keys.split('.'));
  }
});

const info = customAccessor({
  "person": {
    "name": "Something",
    "age": 1
  }
});

console.log(info['person.age']);
info['person.age'] = 10;
console.log(info['person.age']);
```

Comment: While using Proxy in React Component, I update the value with setState then proxy does not give updated result.

Comment: @user8751232 You should include that in the question. Currently it says nothing about using React.

Answer (score 0):

following works

```
info['person']['name']
info.person['name']
info['person'].name
info.person.name
```

and if you **really** want to keep it in one string I suggest writing a small function that splits by "." and then goes through the same steps as above

```
function getValue(obj,path){
     for(let pathPart of path.split('.')){
         obj=obj[pathPart];
     }
     return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function getProperty(obj, property) {
  var locArr = property.split("."), returnVal = obj;
  
  for (let i=0; i<locArr.length; i++) {
    returnVal = returnVal[locArr[i]]
  }
  
  return returnVal
}

console.log(getProperty({
  "person" : {
    "name" : "Something",
    "age" : 1
  }
}, "person.name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `references`

```js
let info = {
    "person" : {
        "name" : "Something",
        "age" : 1
    }
}

let findByName = (name) => {
  let arr = name.split('.')
  let ref = info
  arr.forEach(e => {
    ref = ref[e] ? ref[e]: {}
  })
  return ref
}

console.log(findByName("person.name"))
console.log(findByName("person.age"))
console.log(findByName("person.age.someProp"))
console.log(findByName("person.someProp"))
```